# Kivy: how to display a list with variable rows in Kivy with a RecycleView?

Tags: python, list, listview, android-recyclerview, kivy

I'm new to Python and Kivy, and I need to display a list with variable rows, I'm trying with a recycle view, but I think I'm doing it wrong, and I don't know how it works at all.
here's my code

```
class Introduccion(Screen):
numbers = ObjectProperty()
number_list = ObjectProperty([])

def Add_ToList(self):
    dat = self.numbers.text
    self.number_list.append([dat])
```

and my .kv file

```
<Introduccion>:
    numbers: numbers_input
    number_list: number_list_view
    RelativeLayout:
        pos_hint:{'center_y': 0.8, 'center_x':0.5}
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 700, 200
        pos: 200, 100
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1, 0.1, 0.2, 0
            Rectangle:
                pos: 0,0
                size: self.size
        TextInput:
            id: numbers_input
            size_hint: None, None
            pos: 520, 66
            size: 70, 30
            multiline: False
        Button:
            size_hint: None, None
            pos: 600, 66
            size: 50, 30
            text: "añadir"
            on_press: root.Add_ToList()
    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint:{'center_y': 0.8, 'center_x':0.5}
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 10, 10
        pos: 200, 100
        RecycleView:
            id: number_list_view
            viewclass: 'Label'
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                default_size: None, dp(26)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` of a `RecycleView` is a list of dictionaries with `viewclass` attributes as keys and the value of that attribute as values. Since your `viewclass` is `Label`, an appropriate key in the `data` dictionary is `text`. So your `Introduccion` class can be:

```
class Introduccion(Screen):
    numbers = ObjectProperty()
    number_list = ObjectProperty()

    def Add_ToList(self):
        self.number_list.data.append({'text': str(self.numbers.text)})
```

The `Add_ToList()` method adds a new dictionary to the `RecycleView` `data` on each call. In each case, the key is `text` (referring to the `text` attribute of `Label`), and the value is whatever is in the `TextInput`.

Comment: wow, really thank you very much, I have spent several days looking in forums to document myself but I would not have done it without you, you are my hero

Comment: I am wondering if you know how I can do a RecycleGridLayout with 2 cols where the first column gives me the position of the second column.

Comment: Do you mean position as in the `(x,y)` position of the second? Note that using `Label` as the `viewclass` is only the simplest example. You can create your own class to be used as `viewclass`. Perhaps a `viewclass` that contains two horizontally adjacent `Labels` would do what you want. Your custom `viewclass` just needs `Properties` to be used as keys in the `data`. Internally, the `viewclass` can then define how those `data` values get displayed.